# Is the process of building a model from a dictionary necessarily the builder pattern?

Tags: builder-pattern, groovy

I am working on a tool that scrubs Do-Not-Call (DNC) phone records from a skip-traced CSV file.

I have this `PhoneModel` for child phone entries for each row. It consist of the following fields:

- `isDNC`
- `score` (How accurate is the phone number for that record)
- `phoneType` (Landline, Mobile, ...)
- `phoneNumber`
- `date` (last updated date)

I have code for creating the child phone models from a `MultiValuedMap` of `rawPhoneData`:

```
    public static List<PhoneModel> ExtractFromRawPhoneData(MultiValuedMap<String,Object> rawPhoneData) {
        List<PhoneModel> phoneModels = [];

        PhoneModel model = new PhoneModel();

        List<String> sortedMapKeys = rawPhoneData.keySet()
            // SOURCE: Phind AI
            .sort { String a, String b ->
                int aNum = NumberUtils.ExtractNumber(a);
                int bNum = NumberUtils.ExtractNumber(b);
                return aNum <=> bNum ?: a <=> b
            }
        sortedMapKeys.eachWithIndex({ String key, int idx ->
            model = this.BuildPhoneModel(model, rawPhoneData, key);

            if ((idx < sortedMapKeys.size() - 1) && 
                (NumberUtils.ExtractNumber(sortedMapKeys[idx + 1]) == NumberUtils.ExtractNumber(sortedMapKeys[idx])))
                return;

            if (!StringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(model.phoneNumber))
                phoneModels.add(model);

            model = new PhoneModel();
        })

        return phoneModels;
    }

    private static PhoneModel BuildPhoneModel(PhoneModel originalModel, MultiValuedMap rawPhoneData, String key) { 
        String rawValue = rawPhoneData.get(key)[0];

        if (key.contains(Constants.DncKeyPart)) {
            originalModel.isDNC = new YesNoBooleanConverter().convertStringToBoolean(rawValue);

            return originalModel;
        }

        if (key.contains(Constants.ScoreKeyPart)) {
            originalModel.score = NumberUtils.ParseInt(rawValue);

            return originalModel;
        }

        if (key.contains(Constants.TypeKeyPart)) { 
            if (!StringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(rawValue))
                originalModel.phoneType = PhoneTypes.FromTextValue(rawValue);

            return originalModel;
        }

        if (key.contains(Constants.NumberKeyPart)) {
            originalModel.phoneNumber = rawValue;

            return originalModel;
        }

        if (key.contains(Constants.DateKeyPart)) {
            if (!StringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(rawValue)) 
                originalModel.date = DateUtils.ParseDateTime(rawValue);

            return originalModel;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized key '${key}'");
    }
```

My question here is thus:

**Is my approach to build the `PhoneModel` part-by-part, using dictionary, an implementation of the builder design pattern?**

Comment: What language is this? Java reacts to this with an error on the 2nd line.

Comment: Just a note to help with readability for people reading your code: If this is Java, which it seems to be, the typical convention is that ["methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the *first letter lowercase*, with the first letter of
each internal word capitalized"](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf#G3.367)

Comment: It's written in Groovy

Comment: Why does it matter if someone on the Internet thinks this is or isn't an implementation of a pattern? The important question is whether it solves a problem for you(r team).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builder pattern uses a builder class, which with one final call gives you a fully built object.  The implication of this is that the type system prevents un- or partially constructed (built) objects — at any and every point or place you have a built object, it is 100% complete and ready to use.  (Partially built objects are represented by the instance of the builder class.)

Whereas your approach builds the object in an incremental manner, meaning that you are forgoing the type system support for definitely constructed objects that the builder pattern offers.

---

*As an aside it is curios to use `string.contains` for key matching, though maybe I misunderstand the Groovy method.*

---

*It is also an odd choice to take a dictionary as parameter, and then also a key so as to handle only one item at a time therein.  Why not leave the "dictionary.get()" to the caller and pass both key and value?  That way the function wouldn't rely on the key-value store.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...!

Honestly, I wasn't thinking that many steps ahead...

I was just tryna get this code written, as I was under some operational time pressure, s to produce a DNC-free list for cold calling ;)

As for the decision to see if the key `contains()` a part... I am tryna construct a list of `PhoneModel`s, where the nth part of that `PhoneModel` has key like `Phone${n}_...`

...and what comes after, is a tell-tale sign of what we're dealing with there (DNC flag, score, phone number, phone type, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to constructing the `PhoneModel` from the `rawPhoneData` dictionary does share some similarities with the builder design pattern, but there are some key differences.

***Builder Design Pattern:***

The builder design pattern is used to construct a complex object step by step, and the final step returns the resulting object. The pattern is recognized by:

1. A separate `Builder` class, which provides methods to configure the
   product.
2. A method for retrieving the resulting product.
3. The pattern is particularly useful when an object needs to be created with many optional components or configurations.

***Your Implementation:***

1. You're using static methods within the same class to build the `PhoneModel`.
2. You're building the `PhoneModel` part-by-part based on the keys present in the `rawPhoneData` dictionary.
3. The construction is tightly coupled with the structure and naming conventions of the `rawPhoneData` dictionary.

While your approach does involve constructing an object piece-by-piece based on input data (which is reminiscent of the builder pattern), it doesn't fully encapsulate the builder pattern's separation of concerns and flexibility. In a classic builder pattern, the construction process is abstracted away from the representation of the data. Here, your construction process is directly tied to the structure of the `rawPhoneData`.

So, to answer your question: Your approach has some elements of the builder design pattern, but it's not a strict implementation of it. If you wanted to implement the builder pattern more closely, you might consider creating a separate `PhoneModelBuilder` class that provides methods for setting each attribute of the `PhoneModel` and a final method to return the constructed `PhoneModel`.